# How do I handle nil elements in an array that I am sorting?

Tags: ruby

I am calling `sort` on an array like this:

```
new_list = my_array.sort
```

The error I am getting is:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `<=>' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I handle nil cases for this simple sort?

I initially had a destructive sort call (i.e. `sort!`) and changed it to the regular `sort`, but it still throws this error.

Thoughts?

Comment: show one (or more) inputs and the desired output for them or people will have to guess what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I assume you don't need/want the nils, so...

```
new_list = my_array.compact.sort
```

Comment: What will happen if I have one element in 3D array that is nil? Will it remove the entire record? i.e. `array = [[2, marcamillion, nil], [[3, Ed, 1986]]`.

In that case, what will be compacted? I checked the docs but it doesn't talk about multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ignore nils, you can do this:

```
new_list = my_array.compact.sort
```

[`compact`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) copies the array, skipping `nil` values

Comment: What will happen if I have one element in 3D array that is nil? Will it remove the entire record? i.e. `array = [[2, marcamillion, nil], [[3, Ed, 1986]]`.

In that case, what will be compacted? I checked the docs but it doesn't talk about multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Obviously, it checks only the root level and doesn't go into child arrays. You'd have to code that explicitly.

Comment: Also, it would have taken you less time to test that situation than to write this comment.

Comment: Re-read those comments and see if you could have written them less like a dick.